# In Kotlin, how do you refer to a variable from outside a scoping function when it has the same name as a field in the lambda receiver

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, using a scope function such as "with" that allows the  `this` reference inside the block to reference the lambda result, is it possible to reference the outer class member when it has the same name as one of the fields in the result?

eg

```
data class Person(name: String)
...
class MyClass {
    var name = ""

    with(personRepository.getPerson(personId)) {
        // How do we set the class "name" member - "this.name" or just "name" refers to the scoped object?
        name = this.name // ???
    }
```

Obviously using a different variable name is the simple workaround but just wondering if there is a syntax for when the variables have the same name

```
class MyClass {
    var personName = ""
...
    with(personRepository.getPerson(personId)) {
        personName = this.name
    }
```

Comment: As the answers pointed out, there is the labeled "this@something" syntax. However, please consider using different names when possible, or use another scoping function that doesn't shadow `this`.

Answer (score 7):

the `this` refers to the object that you pass. In order for you to refer to the context of your class you would need to use labels like below. Do note that this is an anti pattern. With scoping functions you would only want to apply logic on the object that you are passing or that is the receiver object in scoping functions like `let` and `apply`

```
class MyClass {
    var name: String = ""
    val person = Person("my name")

    fun setName() = with(person) {
       this@MyClass.name = person.name 
    }
}
```

Comment: Anti pattern is taking it too far I think. :) Sure it's verbose, but sometimes you have to.

Comment: I don't think it has to to with verbosity. It has to do with the fact that you are changing variables in places outside of your scope, exactly what a scoping function is trying to avoid :). That is why i used the word anti-pattern.

Comment: Maybe I'm pedantic, but unlike anti patterns like "shared mutable state" which you should always avoid, "labeled this" has its place and is sometimes needed. But of course, it's not like you would write code to use as many "labeled this"es as possible :P

Comment: "exactly what a scoping function is trying to avoid" I'd disagree here. It's "trying" to bring some extra variables/methods _into_ scope, but only makes it harder to access the outer scope's `name` accidentally.

Comment: Feel free to disagree, but scoping functions are lambda functions. They derive from lambda calculus, meaning for one these functions operate only on their input. Therefore using other properties that are not given as input is imho not done

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `let{}` instead of `with{}`:

```
data class Person(name: String)
...
class MyClass {
    var name = ""

    personRepository.getPerson(personId).let {
    name = it.name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a labeled `this` to refer to the variable in `MyClass`. Like this:

```
with(personRepository.getPerson(personId)) {
    this@MyClass.name = name
}
```